# format integer to string

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an integer field in a table and I want to make a query to format the integer value of this field in an char or double field with a especific format.

For example, if my value in the table is 123456 I want to format it as "###.###" what means the result should be like this: 123.456

I've done this using CONCAT function, but the result is not very elegant. I would like to use another funciont spacific for this purpose.

Comment: What would be the formatted value of 123456789?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this in your presentation layer rather than the DB.

This is pretty easy in C#:

```
// Assuming value is an int
value.ToString("N");
```

More details on formatting int in various ways see the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to use formatting like '###,###.###' ?

Here is the example.

mysql> select FORMAT( 123446, 4 );

+---------------------+

| FORMAT( 123446, 4 ) |

+---------------------+

| 123,446.0000        |

+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select FORMAT( 123446, 0 );

+---------------------+

| FORMAT( 123446, 0 ) |

+---------------------+

| 123,446             |

+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)